# При валидации XML не видит файл DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

```css
<!ELEMENT timeTable (lesson+, offices)> 
<!ELEMENT offices (office+)> 
<!ELEMENT lesson (date?, time?)> 
<!ELEMENT office (name?, address?) > 
<!ATTLIST lesson no CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST office code CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT time (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE timeTable SYSTEM "mydoc.dtd">
<timeTable>
 <lesson no="1">
  <date>2018-05-08</date>
  <time>18:00</time>
 </lesson>
 <lesson no="2">
  <date>2018-05-08</date>
  <time>21:00</time>
 </lesson>
 <offices>
  <office code="БК">
   <name>Комплекс "Бакунинский"</name>
   <address>ул. Бакунинская, 71</address>
  </office>
  <office code="РА">
   <name>Комплекс "Радио"</name>
   <address>ул. Радио,  д.24</address>
  </office>  
 </offices> 
</timeTable>
```

файл mydoc.dtd находится в корне. Проверка валидации осуществляется через Notepad++ инструментом XML Tools

Answer (score 0):

Причину нашел - путь к файлам был очень длинный и названия директорий были на русском и латинице. Перебросил в корень диска в директорию на латинице - все провалидировалось. Если кому пригодится.